# how to get height of a row from gridview extjs 4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

in extjs 3.3.0, i can do that like this

```
var row = grid.getView().getRow(0);
var height = Ext.get(row).getHeight();
```

but i can't find `getRow()` method in gridView from docs api, even in 4.0.2a
anyone know the similar one??

my goal is to reload the grid when the parent window resized. in extjs 3 i do this by get a row height (index 0), then divide the view height with the row height (with rounding). the result will become a new pagesize. finally i reload the store base on new pagesize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var row = grid.getView().getNode(0);
var height = Ext.get(row).getHeight();
```

I just ran into the same thing myself, it got me what I needed. I suspect I'm going through the same pain in the rear upgrade that you are right now too.

-Mark Huber

Answer (score 0):

Best I could find is this:

```
var firstRow = this.getEl().select('tr.x-grid-row').elements[0];
var rowH = Ext.get(firstRow).getHeight();
```

this is your view, I'm trying to dynamically figure out the height of row in a scheme to create a view with only as many rows as can fit in the view's height.